# Converting Strings to two lists in Python

Tags: python, string, list, coordinates

(This is probably really simple, but) Say I have this input as a string:

```
"280.2,259.8 323.1,122.5 135.8,149.5 142.9,403.5"
```

and I want to separate each coordinate point onto separate lists, for each x and y value, so they'd end up looking like this:

```
listX = [280.2, 323.1, 135.8, 142.9]
listY = [259.8, 122.5, 149.5, 403.5]
```

I'd need this to be able to start out with any size string, thanks in advance!

Comment: Wouldn't you want to keep the coordinate pairs together in tuples or something like that rather than separating them in two lists? If you remove the first element in one of the lists, everything collapses

Comment: if you do `[tuple(map(float, x.split(","))) for x in your_string.split(" ")]` you'll get this list of tuples: `[(280.2, 259.8), (323.1, 122.5), (135.8, 149.5), (142.9, 403.5)]`. I don't know your requirements but that's more conventional when working with coordinate pairs.

Comment: @jDo If OP is using numpy for plotting or something it might be useful. Plotting in Numpy takes separate arrays for each dimension.

Comment: @SnakesandCoffee True, good point. I don't know if OP's using numpy, matplotlib, etc. but in that case it would make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy and paste this and it should work:

```
s_input = "280.2,259.8 323.1,122.5 135.8,149.5 142.9,403.5"

listX = [float(x.split(',')[0]) for x in s_input.split()]
listY = [float(y.split(',')[1]) for y in s_input.split()]
```

Answer (score 1):

This would work.

```
my_string="280.2,259.8 323.1,122.5 135.8,149.5 142.9,403.5"
listX =[item.split(",")[0] for item in my_string.split()]
listY=[item.split(",")[1] for item in my_string.split()]
```

or

```
 X_list=[]
 Y_list=[]
 for val in [item.split(",") for item in my_string.split()]:
    X_list.append(val[0])
    Y_list.append(val[1])
```

Which version to use would probably depend on your personal preference and the length of your string.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [split](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.split) method of strings. It should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
>>> a ="280.2,259.8 323.1,122.5 135.8,149.5 142.9,403.5"
>>> b = a.split(" ")
>>> b
['280.2,259.8', '323.1,122.5', '135.8,149.5', '142.9,403.5']
>>> c = [ x.split(',') for x in b]
>>> c
[['280.2', '259.8'], ['323.1', '122.5'], ['135.8', '149.5'], ['142.9', '403.5']]
>>> X = [ d[0] for d in c]
>>> X
['280.2', '323.1', '135.8', '142.9']
>>> Y = [ d[1] for d in c]
>>> Y
['259.8', '122.5', '149.5', '403.5']
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a magical method call `str.split`, which given a string, splits by a delimiter.

Assume we have the string in a variable `s`.

To split by the spaces and make a list, we would do

```
coords = s.split()
```

At this point, the most straightforward method of putting it into the lists would be to do

```
listX = [float(sub.split(",")[0]) for sub in coords]
listY = [float(sub.split(",")[1]) for sub in coords]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a a combination of `zip` and `split` with a list comprehension:

```
s = "280.2,259.8 323.1,122.5 135.8,149.5 142.9,403.5"
l = zip(*[a.split(',') for a in s.split()])
```

This will return a list of 2 tuples.
To get lists instead, use `map` on it.

```
l = map(list, zip(*[a.split(',') for a in s.split()]))
```

`l[0]` and `l[1]` will have your lists.

if your list is huge, consider using `itertools.izip()`